# Как реализовать в БД структуру друзей и подписчиков?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть пользователи и я хочу реализовать в БД структуру друзей и подписчиков.
Подскажите примеры, как обычно такое делается?

Answer (score 0):

Связующая таблица user_connection с полями id, user_id, folower_id, friend(bool)